# Is it possible to deploy an already built Drupal site?

Tags: deployment, drupal

I'm a Drupal newbie. Is it possible to set up everything and deploy Drupal on the server? I mean things like putting in the content, setting up the modules, etc..., then you put it all up to the production server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course.

- copy all the files
- edit the database credentials (sites/default/settings.php)
- export the database content via mysqldump or phpMyAdmin (supposing you use MySQL)
- import the database content at the target server

I've done it several times.

Comment: Yeap, this is what I do, probably 10-20 times per website I build.